# Ajax data shown on table but not appending

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

i am trying to update my table without refreshing the page is my firsttime using ajax so i tried to do it, it shown on the console logs(the data i collect it) but the problem is that the data i got won't appending to my main table can anyone help me?

here is my dashboard.html where i want to update the table

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
   <table id="_appendHere" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>desc</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>price</th>
          </tr>
          {% for i in dest %}
             <td>{{ i.name|upper }}</td>
             <td>{{ i.desc|capfirst }}</td>
             <td>{{ i.status|capfirst }}</td>
             <td>{{ i.price | capfirst}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>
   function updateTable(){
   console.log("hello")
   $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "get_more_table",
      success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
   $("#_appendHere").append(data);
    }
   })
 }
   var interval = setInterval(function () { 
   updateTable(); 
}, 10000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

view

```
def record_table(request):
    dest = Destination.objects.all()
    return render(request,"destination.html",{'dest':dest})

def get_more_table(request): <--- my callback table
    dest = Destination.objects.all()
    return render(request,"get_more_table.html",{'dest':dest})
```

get_more_table.html

```
          {% for i in dest %}
             <td>{{ i.name|upper }}</td>
             <td>{{ i.desc|capfirst }}</td>
             <td>{{ i.status|capfirst }}</td>
             <td>{{ i.price | capfirst}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

here's the picture of my problem it ddnt show any error but the data was print to my console

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CJ18.png)

Comment: What is "data" ? Is it a list of <tr><td> ?

Comment: ```</tr>``` in **get_more_table.html** is not started. Try making that change and let us know.

Comment: to answear mukesh keshu:  yep data is the respon data i ll be getting from get_more_table

Comment: oh crap it work now what a dumb mistake i do thanks